# How do I load an Embedded Signing request with an Envelope ID in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have the API for a demo account setup. So far, I have been able to create a signing request that my demo contact received. I would like to use the Embedded Signing portion of the API to load the recipient view of the Envelope but I get either of these two responses (shown below).

I have the Envelope ID, I know the email and user's name of the (only) recipient, and I can see the this info in the Sandbox UI.

My request has the same JSON Authorization key string used to create the Envelope.

Here are the two sample payloads I am sending (X's replace sensitive info):

Request:

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/110XXXX/envelopes/7dee22f3-90e6-44b0-be6b-XXXXXXX/views/recipient HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"a312a32d-df78-423e-b916-XXXXXXXXX","Password":"XXXXXX","IntegratorKey":"CONN-18a3c56f-f776-40db-8e33-XXXXXXXXX"}
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: BIGipDocuSign=!aI+3n7V3fB0xBxEb7loYjpEeRwCxTKC4na93ET3RH8aETpEeGTqTaKaY1y6ui+nhmrX85Xa90CfKgfk=
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: close
Content-Length: 186

{
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "email": "adam@example.com",
  "returnUrl": "http://lvh.me:3000",
  "userName": "John Smith",
  "clientUserId":"21"
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 152
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1436846400
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 998
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 03:43:01 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: BIGipDocuSign=!aI+3n7V3fB0xBxEb7loYjpEeRwCxTKC4na93ET3RH8aETpEeGTqTaKaY1y6ui+nhmrX85Xa90CfKgfk=;secure; path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

{
  "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
  "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

----- OR -----

Request:

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/110XXXX/envelopes/7dee22f3-90e6-44b0-be6b-XXXXXXX/views/recipient HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"a312a32d-df78-423e-b916-XXXXXXXXX","Password":"XXXXXX","IntegratorKey":"CONN-18a3c56f-f776-40db-8e33-XXXXXXXXX"}
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: BIGipDocuSign=!aI+3n7V3fB0xBxEb7loYjpEeRwCxTKC4na93ET3RH8aETpEeGTqTaKaY1y6ui+nhmrX85Xa90CfKgfk=
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: close
Content-Length: 158

{ 
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "email": "adam@example.com",
  "returnUrl": "http://lvh.me:3000",
  "userName": "John Smith"
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 140
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1436846400
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 997
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 03:53:06 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: BIGipDocuSign=!J6eG9xlLFCmIIZgb7loYjpEeRwCxTPgRydEJMtaaTaMNaqpZpXKRTbRGctfwEWaI3Ptas3QeaupEj2o=;secure; path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

{
  "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE",
  "message": "This account is not authorized to access the requested envelope."
}
```

Comment: To do embedded signing, you definitely need to include the clientUserID. Given what you said about the credentials used, I would recommend a sanity check against the actual recipient data to ensure you are specifying the EXACT same name/email@/clientUserID that you believe is associated with this signer. I recommend doing a GET against the /envelope/<envelopeID>/recipients endpoint and examine the contents

Comment: They are indeed the same. What should `clientUserID` contain?

Comment: When you CREATE the envelope via the API, specifying a clientUserID for a recipient means that signer/recipient will only be able to sign this through embedded signing. They will not receive an email to begin signing from DocuSign. In short, if clientUserID exists = embedded signing, clientUserID does not exist = remote/email initiated signing.  I'd recommend checking our documentation for additional details re: clientUserID: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=clientuserid

Comment: Just posted a lengthy answer, hopefully that helps resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following the [Quickstart](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#quickstart) and the documentation found in the DocuSign Developer Center.  There's a whole section in the quickstart that explains Embedded Signing, and there's also a features page dedicated to [Embedding functionality](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) that has all the info you need.

---

**Step 1: Create an envelope with an Embedded Recipient**

To designate a recipient as embedded (meaning they will NOT initiate the request through email but rather through your app) you simply set the recipient's `clientUserId` property to a non-null value - your first example looks fine with it set to `21`.  A typical envelope definition for this looks like:

```
{
    "documents": [{
        "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Test"
    }],
    "emailSubject": "Testing",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "name": "John Doe",         
            "email": "john@email.com",
            "clientUserId": "21",               
            "recipientId": "1"
        }]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Since the clientUserId is set for this recipient they will not receive an email notification when the request is sent (though that's an account setting you can modify to still send the email if wanted).

API Method:  [Envelopes: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/)

---

**Step 2: Request the Recipient View (aka Embedded Signing)**

Once the envelope has been sent with an embedded recipient you simply need to generate the signing URL. To generate the signing URL you must supply the same exact recipient parameters that were provided when the recipient was added to the envelope. In other words, you must supply the same exact `userName`, `email`, and `clientUserId`. *Note that the Name field is called `userName` in this API as opposed to just `name` which was used in the create envelope API*.

A typical request for this looks like:

```
{
    "authenticationMethod": "email",
    "userName": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@email.com",              
    "clientUserId": "21",
    "returnUrl": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

API Method:  [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/)